# Find $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt {2x^2+3}}{4x+2}$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt {2x^2+3}}{4x+2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

I was reading about limits of functions from Problems of Calculus in One Variable written by I.A Maron. There was an example given in the book:

Find $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt {2x^2+3}}{4x+2}$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt {2x^2+3}}{4x+2}$.

The solution given in the book is as follows:
[image]

However, I dont get how they conclude "From this it follows, incidentally, that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt {2x^2+3}}{4x+2}$ does not exist." ? I am not quite getting it...

For a more accurate reference of the question, I am attaching a picture of how the question was presented in the book:[image]

Comment: Their comment is completely wrong! If you quoted correctly, my conclusion is that the author of that text is not very careful.

Comment: It seems like they're mixing up the notion of the one-sided limits

$$\lim_{x \to c^+} \qquad \lim_{x \to c^-}$$

with the limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively.

Comment: I'm guessing that for the author $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ means something else than ${\lim_{x \to +\infty}}$. Admittedly, I've never seen that, but I can imagine a definition in which $L = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is equivalent to $L = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \land L = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$.

Comment: @coffeemath That may be the case . I have posted a picture of the solution as a proof , but yeah, I think the comment is completely wrong! ...

Comment: [reading the other comments perhaps the author is using $x \to \infty$ to mean a combination of the *two* cases $x \to \pm \infty.$ However in  Calc texts I've come across, $\infty$ has the same meaning as $+\infty.$

Comment: I cannot find anything in the book to back up my idea that the author is using $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ to mean something non-standard. I can find lots of places in the book to back up @coffeemath's conclusion that the author is not very careful, though.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Yeah, the book may have many nitpicks, in general...

Comment: As @coffeemath writes, the author uses common notation $\infty$ for both $+\infty$ and $-\infty,$ see e.g. p.56. In this sense is the argumentation correct.

Comment: I have just checked my copy of Maron, the OP is right and Maron is wrong.

Comment: @user376343 I cannot completely agree with this, as say in the first question it asks for $x\to\infty$ so there is no question of considering the case when $-x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Franklin you cannot agree :) everything depends on notations and definitions. In this book, the author uses what I wrote. Also me, as a student, was instructed to write $+\infty$ or $-\infty,$ because $\infty$ was a common notation for both. This was consistent with $\infty$ used in complex numbers. We used often Russian books.

Answer (score 1):

This use of $\infty$ is actually very common for complex analysis. And if we consider the limit at $\infty$ to be over the complex numbers, the author is completely correct - the fact that the real limits at $\pm\infty$ are different shows that the complex limit at $\infty$ cannot exist. That the author appears to be treating the limit at $\infty$ as a real limit is unusual, but not unheard of. Once you've learned the complex equivalent, it is obvious that the same concept can be applied to the real numbers to have them curl around and approach a single $\infty$ at both ends.

In $\Bbb R^3$, consider the plane $z = 0$ to be the complex plane, with $(x,y, 0)\equiv x + iy$. Now consider the unit sphere $S^2 = \{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$, and label $(0,0,1)$ as $n$, the "north pole". For each complex number $w$, the line passing through $n$ and $w$ will intersect the sphere in one other point $w'$. If $|w| = 1$, then $w$ and $w'$ coincide. And every point the sphere other than $n$ corresonds to a unique complex number in this way. You can view the points on the sphere as being the complex numbers in this fashion. But we have one extra point $n$ on the sphere. Points in neighborhoods of $n$ are those with large absolute value, without regard to direction, with the absolute values getting larger as the neighborhood of $n$ gets smaller. Thus it makes sense to consider the north pole to be a single infinite complex number that one arrives at no matter how they grow without bound. It is labeled just "$\infty$". The sphere consisting of $\Bbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ is called "the Riemann sphere" after its inventor and is familiar to every student of complex analysis.

Applying the same concept to the unit circle in the plane, with the real numbers acting at the $x$-axis, wraps the real numbers into a circle with a single $\infty$ as the pole.

And for this expression, since the limit at $-\infty$ is not the same as the limit at $+\infty$, it approaches different values on each side of $\infty$ and that limit cannot exist.

Answer (score -2):

$$
\text { Noting that } \sqrt{x^2}=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
x & \text { if } x \geq 0 \\
-x & \text { if } x<0
\end{array}\right.
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2 x^2+3}}{4 x+2} & =\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}} \sqrt{2 x^2+3}}{4+\frac{2}{x}} \\
& =\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2+\frac{3}{x^2}}}{4+\frac{2}{x}} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2 x^2+3}}{4 x+2} & =-\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{x} \sqrt{2 x^2+3}}{4+\frac{2}{x}} \\
& =-\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2+\frac{3}{x^2}}}{4+\frac{2}{x}} \\
& =-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \\
& =-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$